# Clojure: speccing a couple of constraints; forced to "break out" into a predicate. Any better way?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I have this structure to tile the 2D plane with squares:

- A "strip" is an ensemble of "squares" with the same x coordinate.
- A struct-map representing the strip holds said x coordinate as `::sq-x` and a map of squares at that x coordinate as `::squares`.
- The keys of the map of squares are the square's y-coordinates.
- The values of the map of squares are the squares.
- A square is a struct-map with the x and y coordinates of the square as `::sq-x` and `::sq-y` respectively, and a vector of "vertices" `::vtxs`.

There are of course equality constraints between the square `::sq-x` and the strip's `::sq-x` as well as the square `::sq-y` and the map key.

[image: strip & square data structure]

As we don't declare these structures in Clojure, speccing them becomes somewhat the backbone that is class/type declarations in Java.

It is rather clear how to spec the basic structure, but in order to spec the map and the two constraints I have to "break out" into a predicate `check-squares-map`.

```
(ns foo.bar
   (:require
      [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
      [clojure.test       :as t]))

(s/def ::sq-x integer?)
(s/def ::sq-y integer?)
(s/def ::vtxs sequential?)
(s/def ::square  (s/keys :req [::sq-x ::sq-y ::vtxs]))

; ---
; Additional constraining of values
; ---
; Receive: the "strip", which is dezz'd ("destructured") into the "sq-x"
; master value and the "squares" map.
; What is done:
; - Transform the "squares" map into a lazy seq of booleans where "true" 
;   means constraints for that map entry passed.
; - Use every? on that seq for early return.

(defn- check-squares-map [{sq-x-master ::sq-x squares ::squares}]
   (every?
      (fn [key+val]
         ; dezz the pair key+val into: "sq-y-as-key" and a dezz'd "square"
         (let [[ skey { sq-x ::sq-x sq-y ::sq-y vtxs ::vtxs } ] key+val ]
            (and
               (= sq-x sq-x-master)
               (= skey sq-y))))
      squares))

; ---
; spec-ing the "map of 'square' structs"
; ---
; We need a "map?" predicate because "s/every-kv" actually accepts
; '[]' as valid "associative collection".
; Note that s/every-kv will not necessarily check every "square" when
; called (it breaks off at some point)

(s/def ::squares
   (s/and
      map?
      (s/every-kv ::sq-y ::square)))

; ---
; spec-ing the "strip" struct
; ---
; This spec constrains the "strip" struct.
; .. which transitively constrains the "squares" map.
; .... which transitively constrains the individual "square" structs in
; the "squares" map.
; But we need to enforce a "remote constraint" between a "square",
; the keys of the "squares" map the "strip". Which is done by calling the
; "check-squares-map" predicate. This is unsatisfying, as calling the predicate
; breaks good spec-reporting.

(s/def ::strip
   (s/and
      (s/keys :req [::sq-x ::squares])
      #(check-squares-map %)))
```

Note that the spec `::squares` will not necessarily check every square: [every-kv.](https://clojure.github.io/spec.alpha/clojure.spec.alpha-api.html#clojure.spec.alpha/every-kv)

The "breakout" is unfortunate because then `s/explain` will just say "the predicate failed" but not where exactly:

> ```
> (s/explain ::strip
>    {::sq-x 500
>    ::squares
>    {0 { ::sq-x 66 ::sq-y 66 ::vtxs [] }}})
>
>    #:foo.bar{:sq-x 500, :squares 
>       {0 #:foo.bar{:sq-x 66, :sq-y 66, :vtxs []}}} 
>       - failed: (check-squares-map %) spec: :foo.bar/strip
> ```

We have a failure because `::sq-x` is 500 on the "strip" but 66 on the "square". Similar mismatch between the key at 0 and the `::sq-y` at 66. But the message is pretty general.

Is there a coding style or a way to amend the above to increase the "spec-icity" of `::strip` spec so that the breakout into a predicate can be minimized? In particular, the constraint between values of separate structure-maps seems hard to express. speccing is rather "local" (or is it?)

Comment: If the x-coord of the squares must always match the x-coord of the strip-map which contains it, why does the square need to have an x-coordinate?To quote William of Occam, "Entities should not be multiplied beyond necessity".

Comment: @BobJarvis Let's just say that these structure are created elsewhere, then assembled at a later time. But I'm more interested in finding out how to spec those constraints than in data structures. (Note that Occam talked about phenomeonolgy, not data structures. Otherwise people might take him by his word and any caching and data optimization would go right out of the window)

Answer (score 0):

This question shows the limits of using **types** to catch errors in **data**.

A type in Java, for example, can easily distinguish between int or float.  It is not so good as separating out ***valid*** values of int or float, such as odd is OK but even is bad, or only values in the range `[0..12)`.  Indeed, some types (such as irrational numbers) cannot be represented exactly at all.

---

A better approach (if practicable for your problem) would be to re-organize the data structure to avoid possible internal conflicts (such as conflicting `:sq-x` values).  For example, you could define a "strip" more like this:

```
- x          ; the x value (lower-left corner)
- y-min      ; the lowest y value (also LL corner)
- len        ; y-max = y-min + len (inclusive or exclusive both work here)
- size       ; the width/height of each square (if necessary)
```

Using the above, you could also compute the vertexes of each square whenever needed.  You could also number the squares from min to max as `[0..(len-1)]` in case you ever wanted to access the coordinates of a specific square.

Comment: Thanks Alan. So what you are saying is that specs are akin to types (HiMi or otherwise) and breakouts into general predicate code to perform some checks is expected? I see the rationale behind changing the data structure, but assume it is left as is. It seems what is missing to avoid this freely coded predicate business would a parametrized spec: A spec that is handed not only the value to be specced but also at least one additional parameter (possibly a map) computed in an enclosing spec, giving additional constraints to be verified (the feel of a dependent type becomes stronger).

Comment: ... But wait, this can actually be done by appropriate construction! Or can it? Create a new spec of the original thing-to-be-specced, adjoined with additional parameters? I got to try that later.

Comment: Perhaps those constraints would be better spec'ed on the functions that assemble the structure later, rather than the structure itself? That way some context more specific to the operation may be more readily available.

Answer (score 0):

After reflection, I have found this.

That's not it yet, as some tests pass that should fail. BRB.

```
(ns foo.bar
   (:require
      [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
      [clojure.test       :as t]))

(s/def ::sq-x integer?)
(s/def ::sq-y integer?)
(s/def ::vtxs sequential?)
(s/def ::square  (s/keys :req [::sq-x ::sq-y ::vtxs]))

; ---
; spec-ing the "map of 'square' structs"
; ---
; We need a "map?" predicate because "s/every-kv" actually accepts
; '[]' as valid "associative collection".
; Note that s/every-kv will not necessarily check every "square" when
; called (it breaks off at some point)

(s/def ::squares
   (s/and
      map?
      (s/every-kv ::sq-y ::square)))

; ---
; Is this right?
; ---
; Here we assemble a new spec to be used in ::strip).
; The assemble function takes two parameters and returns a spec,
; i.e. a function taking a "strip" struct.
; (Can I even return a spec function from inside a let? Should work,
;  no impediment to this orthogonality that I can see)

(defn assemble-new-spec [sq-x-master squares]
   (fn [strip]
      (let [squares (get strip ::squares)]
         ((s/and
             (s/every (fn [keey vaal] (= sq-x-master (get vaal ::sq-x))))
             (s/every (fn [keey vaal] (= keey (get vaal ::sq-y)))))
          strip)))) ; and here we pass "strip" to the s/and for evaluation

(s/def ::strip
   (s/and
      (s/keys :req [::sq-x ::squares])
      #(assemble-new-spec (get % ::sq-x) (get % ::squares)))) ; hmm....
```

This sadly fails at the REPL.

Take the erroneous structure

```
#:foo.bar{:sq-x 1, :squares {0 #:foo.bar{:sq-x 66, :sq-y 0, :vtxs []}}}
```

where `sq-x` is 1 on one side, but 66 on the other side.

Doesn't work:

> ```
> $ lein repl
> ```

---

```
(require  '[clojure.test       :as t    :refer [deftest testing is]]
          '[clojure.spec.alpha :as s    :refer [valid?]]
          '[foo.bar            :as sut])

(def borked {
   ::sut/sq-x 1
   ::sut/squares {0 { ::sut/sq-x 66 ::sut/sq-y 0 ::sut/vtxs [] }}})

(valid? ::sut/strip borked)
;=> true
```

Aiee.